# What is the purpose of class and class device?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I followed some tutorials that explained how to write Linux kernel modules and I am a bit confused. Even after reading the [official "documentation"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/text/class.txt), I have poor understanding of the concepts.

After creating a character device (`register_chrdev`), I see it is common to use a combination of the following functions:

`class_create`

`class_device_create`

`device_create`

I was not able to understand, what is a `class`, `device` and, `class device` and driver?

Which one of these actually responsible to create an entry under `/proc/`?

Comment: Forget about */proc*, nowadays devices are advertised through sysfs.

Comment: @0andriy Can you suggest any good reading about the correct and modern way of  writing device drivers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than going into ***what's a class***, or ***what's a device*** (I'm no expert in Linux kernel), I will address the question as follows.

After creating the character device, you want to be able to access it from the user space. To do this, you need to add a device node under `/dev`. You can do this in two ways.

**Use `mknod` to manually add a device node (old)**

`mknod /dev/<name> c <major> <minor>`

OR

**Use `udev`**

This is where the [class_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4/source/drivers/base/class.c#L249) and [device_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4/source/drivers/base/core.c#L1582) or [class_device_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.24/source/drivers/base/class.c#L681) (old) come in.

To notify `udev` from your kernel module, you first create a virtual device class using

`struct class * class_create(owner, name)`

Now, the name will appear in `/sys/class/<name>`.

Then, create a device and register it with sysfs.

`struct device *device_create(struct class *class, struct device *parent,
                 dev_t devt, void *drvdata, const char *fmt, ...)`

Now, device name will appear in `/sys/devices/virtual/<class name>/<device name>` and `/dev/<device name>`

It's not clear what you are asking about the `/proc` entry.

After your module is loaded, it will appear in `/proc/modules` (do a `cat /proc/modules` to see it). And, after you allocate the device numbers, say with

`int register_chrdev_region(dev_t first, unsigned int count, char *name)`

, the name will appear in `/proc/devices` (do a `cat /proc/devices` to see it).

And, please check the kernel sources for these functions as well, as they provide a good description of what they do in their comments.

The good old [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) does not provide these mechanisms, but it's a very good source.

Comment: is there any logic in class names? 
for example this one: 
/sys/class/leds/omega2p:amber:system
what is :amber:system mean?!
thanks

Comment: @aleXela I think you can give any descriptive name for the class. Here, `amber` could be the led color, and `system` could be related to the led's designated functionality. I just did a search and found [this](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/the-omega-led.html). If you have the sources, you can see how it is implemented.

Comment: @dhanushka any points on why class.h file is empty in kernel headers?

Comment: @RaHuL Can you please provide a link to the particular file you are talking about (e.g. from Elixir Bootlin)?

Comment: sure @dhanushka...this is the link https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/device/class.h#L273. So in my system the class.h is empty(no contents) i dont know why and how class_create gets linked without that header. Thanks.

Comment: @RaHuL Then the `class_create` macro should be in a different header, probably device.h? You can perform a search and verify it's there in a header.

Comment: thanks much @dhanushka its there in device.h.