# What is the difference between __class_create() and class_create() in the Kernel API?

Tags: module, kernel

Referring to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837481) and to [2](https://programmer.help/blogs/device_create-device_register-deivce_add-differences.html), among others, it seems the kernel API comes with a function `class_create()` that takes two arguments.

However, within that API [3](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/infrastructure.html?highlight=class_create#c.__class_create), I can only find out a function named `__class_create()` that requires three arguments.

What is the difference between `class_create()` and `__class_create()`?
Is the former obsolete?
Where is the documentation of `class_create()`?

Answer (score 0):

"class_create()" is a function-like-macro defined into include/linux/device/class.h, this is not a function.
It substitutes the definition of a static structure it directly passes to "__class_create()" as follows:

```
#define class_create(owner, name)       \
({                      \
    static struct lock_class_key __key; \
    __class_create(owner, name, &__key);    \
})
```

Therefore, "__class_create()" is present into the kernel API.

"__class_create()"'s prototype can be found into the same header file.